# MEF and PlugIn properties updates

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mef

I'm new to MEF and started a project to test it. What I'm trying to do is opening a MainForm that would load plugins based on an Interface. Those plugins need to be able to exchange information between them and the MainForm should be able to communicate with all of them too. So I started by creating my MainForm that loads a plugin. The plugin is only a form containing a ListBox. On the MainForm I have a button. I want that button to send a List(of String) to the plugin and that plugin to load that List(of String) in the ListBox. Currently, when I click on the MainForm button, it sends the list to the plugin. But the list is not loading in the plugin ListBox. Looking to find the problem, I added a new button on the MainForm to verify that the plugin property actually contains the list(of string) I sent it. And yes, the list contains all my strings. The problem needs to be that the ListBox isn't refreshing?

Part of the interface:

```
Public Interface IPlugIn

   Property PlugInName as string
   Property Files As List(Of String)

End Interface
```

Code in the MainForm Button:

```
    Dim currentPlugIn As Contract.API.IPlugIn

    currentPlugIn = PlugIns.Find(Function(x) x.PlugInName = "Test")

    currentPlugIn.Files = IO.Directory.GetFiles("SomeFolder").ToList
```

Code in the PlugIn:

```
<Export(GetType(Contract.API.IPlugIn))> _
Public Class UserControl1
   Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged, Contract.API.IPlugIn

Public Property Files As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String) Implements
   Contract.API.IPlugIn.Files
    Get
        If IsNothing(_files) Then
            _files = New List(Of String)
        End If

        Return _files
    End Get
    Set(value As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String))
        _files = value

        OnPropertyChanged("Files")
    End Set
End Property

Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As 
   System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements
   System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New 
    ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub
```

Code in PlugIn XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="lstFiles" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}"/>
```

What's the problem? I searched the Internet for examples and found hundreds, but none of them is showing how to do what I want to do. Just before posting my question here, I added the INotifyPropertyChanged, it didn't resolved the problem. Would it be better for me to use PRISM, Caliburn.Micro or is MEF only going to be okay?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone!

I finally found the answer.

I implemented PRISM EventAggregator and did change the following

In the Interface and PlugIns

Completely removed

```
Public ReadOnly Property PlugInUI As System.Windows.Controls.UserControl Implements 
Contract.API.IPlugIn.PlugInUI
   Get
      Dim myUI As New UserControl1

      Return myUI
   End Get
End Property
```

In the Host

Changed

```
Public Sub OnImportsSatisfied() Implements 
System.ComponentModel.Composition.IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification.OnImportsSatisfied
    For Each plugInItem In WidgetList
        Desktop.Children.Add(plugInItem.PlugInView)
    Next
End Sub
```

to

```
Public Sub OnImportsSatisfied() Implements 
System.ComponentModel.Composition.IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification.OnImportsSatisfied
    For Each plugInItem In WidgetList
        Desktop.Children.Add(plugInItem)
    Next
End Sub
```

And now everything works as I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Athari, thanks for your comment.

I did fix the properties to ObservableCollection, but didn't fix the problem. Seems I'm missing something else.

Here's the full code.

Interface

```
Namespace API

   Public Interface IPlugIn

      Property Files As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of String)
      ReadOnly Property PlugInUI As System.Windows.Controls.UserControl

   End Interface

End Namespace
```

PlugIn

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition

<Export(GetType(Contract.API.IPlugIn))> _
Public Class UserControl1
Implements Contract.API.IPlugIn, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged, 
   System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged

Private _files As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of String)

Public Property Files As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of String)     
  Implements Contract.API.IPlugIn.Files
    Get
        If IsNothing(_files) Then
            _files = New System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of String)
        End If
        Return _files
    End Get
    Set(value As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of String))
        _files = value
        OnPropertyChanged("Files")
        OnCollectionChanged(New 
          Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs _
          (Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))
    End Set
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property PlugInUI As System.Windows.Controls.UserControl Implements 
Contract.API.IPlugIn.PlugInUI
    Get
        Dim myUI As New UserControl1

        Return myUI
    End Get
End Property

Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As 
    System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements      
    System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(Optional propertyName As String = Nothing)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New 
      ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub

Public Event CollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As 
  System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) Implements 
  System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged

Public Sub OnCollectionChanged(args As 
  System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
    RaiseEvent CollectionChanged(Me, args)
End Sub

End Class
```

PlugIn XAML

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Height="248" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,31,0,0" Name="ListBox1" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="241" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
</Grid>
```

Host App

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition
Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting

Public Class HostApp

<ImportMany(GetType(Contract.API.IPlugIn))> _
Public Property PlugIns As List(Of Contract.API.IPlugIn)
Private _container As CompositionContainer

Public Sub Compose()
    Dim catalog As New AggregateCatalog

    catalog.Catalogs.Add(New DirectoryCatalog("pluginfolder"))

    _container = New CompositionContainer(catalog)

    _container.ComposeParts(Me)
End Sub

Public Sub LoadPlugIns()
    Compose()

    For Each item In PlugIns
        Desktop.Children.Add(item.PlugInUI)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub HostApp_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) 
Handles Me.Loaded
    LoadPlugIns()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) 
Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fileList As New Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of String)

    For Each fileItem As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("Somefolder")
        fileList.Add(fileItem)
    Next

    PlugIns.Item(0).Files = fileList
End Sub

End Class
```

I need the Files property to be listed in the PlugIn ListBox.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I continue trying many things and found something really weird.
I added a button on the HostApp that get the count of string in Files PlugIn and it returns the quantity of string correctly.
I also added a button on the PlugIn that get the count of string in Files and it returns 0!

Why does the PlugIn exists in "two different instance" one in the host and one plugin-only?